# ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize my dvd r/w lightscribe drive

Tags: system-installation, dvd

I am running an HP Pavilion dv6700 with ubuntu 14.04 installed. I am new to Linux OS. I have typed in the command at the prompt "sudo lshw -C disk" and all that shows up is the harddrive. I have looked inside the contents of the folder /dev and saw nothing like cd/cdrom/dvd/drive etc. When at the prompt and I type "sudo lshw" I see lots of information about hardware components but I can't make out anything relating to the dvd drive. How can I get this OS to find and recognize and make fully operational this perfectly good dvd drive?
Thank you to all who can assist!

Comment: That does seem odd. You're doing the right thing there as far as I'm concerned.  That's a notebook; am I correct in assuming that the drive came with it?   I wonder if it's IDE or SATA interface.  You might try perusing the output of dmesg to see if you see any mention of a CD/DVD.

Comment: You are correct, the drive came with. The user's manual says describes it as "Parallel ATA". I took a look at the output of dmesg as you suggested and didn't find anything for CD or DVD.

Comment: You might examine the output of lshw (you could try "lshw -short" first so all the details don't distract) to see if you can find the parallel controller itself.  The answer won't solve your problem, but it *might* provide a clue.  I'm pretty, er, clueless right now.

Comment: here's what I get from lshw -short:

Comment: I don't see anything about "Parallel" or "ATA"                                                                                                                                      H/W path        Device     Class      Description
=================================================
/0/6                       storage    MCP67 IDE Controller
/0/8/5                     bus        R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
/0/9                       storage    MCP67 AHCI Controller
/0/12    display    C67 [GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M

Comment: I'm sure the IDE controller is the right device.  It doesn't show any sub-devices on it (0/6/x), though, again confirming that Linux doesn't seem ready to admit that there's any optical drive attached to it.  I'm stumped.